# Can I have Apple replace my wireless card with a newer model

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos, continuity

I have a 15" MBP mid 2010. I also have a 3rd gen iPad 64GB wifi which I have recently discovered (following update to IOS 8.xxlatest) is unable to work with AIR DROP. I thought about upgrading to the iPad Air 2. Fortunately, I didn't as I now discover that my MBP might not work with Air Drop either.

I find NO reference on my MBP to "handoff". My wireless card is the BCM43xx 1.0. According to another community supplied "Continuity Tool", it says I need a new Wireless card.
 Since this is not a 17" (never seen one), there are NO additional ports to add in a newer wireless card. My wireless in-house network seems to function just fine.

When I click on Air Drop on the side panel, I see my wife's MBP show up. However, I click on it and nothing happens. What am I missing?

QUESTION: Do I need a newer wireless card for AIR DROP to work. I am running Yosemite.

Air Drop should work with my two MBPs. Question is, will they?

Answer (score 1):

OK, never mind. I just discovered all the old info regarding "handoff" is no longer pertinent. All I do is drop a file on the air drop id I see and they get a question pop up asking to save & open, deny or save. Puts it in the download folder.

However, the iPad 3rd gen still does NOT support air drop. Boo hoo. At least, if I get an iPad air 2, it should work with air drop.